# Why is it that my favicon does not appear in Firefox and IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I specified my favicon like this in the `<head>` area:

```
<link href="/Content/images/icons/tick-circle.png" type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon">
<link href="/Content/images/icons/tick-circle.png" type="image/png" rel="icon">
```

The location is correct but when I open up a page I still do not see my icon. I thought these were the two latest ways to specify the ico for the latest versions of IE and Firefox.

Comment: `image/x-icon` is **not** the correct mime-type for a PNG file. So unless you use content-negotiation on the icon URL the first line is simply wrong.

Comment: It's most probably a cache problem (but it's somehow not cleared when you clear your browser cache...). Try it on another browser

Comment: clear the browser cache or remove any existing bookmarks to the site. in chrome, i get this stuck favicon all the time.

Answer (score 4):

Although your favicon can be a png, in my opinion an actual file ending in .ico works best. Also, use a full domain name (i.e. http://www.domain.com/images/favicon.ico), dont rely on relative links. If you tried loading a favicon in your browser and it failed, simply refreshing the page never loads it back. Clear your browser's cache, then try to see if the favicon appears.

The below 3 favicon links work for FF, Opera, Chrome, IE and Apple products

Your code 'should' look like this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://www.domain.com/content/images/icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.domain.com/content/images/icons/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://www.domain.com/content/images/icons/favicon.ico">
```

If you want to leave your relative links without the .ico extension:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/content/images/icons/tick-circle.png" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/content/images/icons/tick-circle.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/content/images/icons/tick-circle.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

favicon is one of those weird gotcha's.

make the favicon on the root of the website and call it `favicon.ico` ie

```
<link href="/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" rel="icon" />
```

refer to the `Accessibility' section in Wikipedia [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Accessibility)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="your icon path">
```

Make sure once you done remove all your cache and restart the browser. Only chrome will display on the spot once you add.

Also try to use ico file instead of png or other.

Answer (score 0):

Older browser wants this to be in the `.ico` format, and not the png. Do consider changing it.

You can do it simple through converters, like [this one](http://www.convertico.com/).

Appart from that, do as mentioned and have it like

```
 <link href="\favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" rel="icon" />
```

instead.

For troubleshooting this, emptying all cache and not just the last hours might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

do you have something like this in your .htaccess and the edited the image or something

```
# Sample of what if have in mine. this restricts the download the time you specify
# 480 weeks
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

It's remotely your problem. but somethig like this could be blocking the browser to retrieve those files extensions. In that case, try crearling your browser's cache?

Comment: The original question doesn't mention the type of server.  What about IIS?

Answer (score 0):

PNG has never worked for favicons in IE. Just yesterday I read Firefox changed to only using the .ico format but I can't confirm this. I tried this and found out png didn't work in FF for me either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about IE, but FireFox has decided to no longer display favicons for security reasons (i.e. you could put a green 'lock' as your favicon and could mislead users to believe your site is secure.)

Here's a writeup: http://www.neowin.net/news/firefox-removing-favicons-from-the-address-bar

**UPDATE**: As for the favicon... use this markup:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
```

I believe the problem with your original code was the '/' before `Content` in the path to the favicon.

Comment: Not sure about the writeup but I have the latest version of FF and it displays favicons just fine...

Comment: They're disabling them in a future release. I updated my answer for what you should use.